# codeigniter 404 page not found in intranet deployment

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

Please guide me what is the issue? All of my pages are showing 404 not found in intranet deployment, while main (home) page is viewing fine.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dna/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dna/index.php/$1 [L]
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = 'error/index';
$route['pages/(:any)']="pages/view/$1";
$route['contact-us'] = 'contact_us/index';
$route['news'] = 'news/index';
```

I'll be grateful for any help or guidance.

Comment: Could the RewriteBase have changed? Could `/dna/` in the .htaccess be the issue? Trying different values for _URI Protocol_ in your config may also help.

Comment: try change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dna/index.php/$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`, you are already setting `/dna/` in `RewriteBase /dna/`. Unless you want it to point at http://<domain>/dna/dna/home

Comment: Its still not working! "The requested URL /dna/pages/home was not found on this server."

Comment: What were the URLs you are using for development and live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter automatically gets $config['base_url'] for your site, so you can leave that blank
Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled.
then modify your .htaccess with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^site_hostname.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

hope that solves it.

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter have issues with subfolders.

Create new virtual host like `dna.example.com`

Remove `dna/` from `.htaccess` and `base_url` settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dna/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The above will work assuming you have set the correct `$config['base_url']` in config

`$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/DNA/"` or similar depending on your set-up.